# Program run perfectly in pycharm, gives incorrect answer when run in terminal

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm

Background. 4th-year comp sci student. First-year python.

> **Problem:** I am running a program in two places, Pycharm (IDE) and an external server using the terminal. The output for the same python
>   file is different when running on these two things. I need it to be
>   the same and preferably correct. (and yes, python and the fasta file
>   is the same on the terminal and the Pycharm).

#### **Files on pycharm and terminal.**

**Pycharm files:**

1. chromosome9.fa
2. Window.py
3. Command to run: python Window.py chromosome9.fa

**terminal files**

1. chrom9.fa
2. Window.py
3. Command to run: python Window.py chrom9.fa

## **Output of the Pycharm file**

```
There are 1255728 CpG pairs in this sequence.


[(63385200, 63385679), (64711680, 64712169), (65825370, 65825849), (131739850, 131740259), (134326260, 134326859)]

[(1092400, 1092839), (1366440, 1366849), (1549650, 1550099), (4068100, 4068849), (4326450, 4327169), (9216770, 9217449), (12647450, 12648029), (14136430, 14136909), (15126110, 15126569)
, (29073770, 29074689), (39586690, 39587139), (73198340, 73198929), (74377730, 74378379), (75009180, 75009779), (75341380, 75341889), (99970290, 99970769), (103436370, 103436809)]

getting average CpGIsland length for + strand
Average length: 491.0

getting average CpGIsland length for - strand
Average length: 564.2941176470588
```

## **Output for the terminal program**

```
('There are', 1255728, 'CpG pairs in this sequence.')

[]

[]


getting average CpGIsland length for + strand
Average length : 0

getting average CpGIsland length for - strand
Average length : 0
```

The print statement

```
print("There are",len(CG_indices),"CpG pairs in this sequence.")
```

also prints different for both but I don't care about that currently.

**Anyone knows what is happening?**

Comment: First guess is that the interpreter Pycharm is using is different from the interpreter that terminal is using

Comment: And a second guess is basically impossible without the relevant parts of the code. Have a look here how to create a [mcve].

Comment: A hint that Python 2 on the server vs Python 3 in the IDE might be the answer: When doing `print(something, something_else)` in Python 2 this prints a tuple, while in Python 3 the parenthesis are needed because `print` is a function and no longer a statement.

Comment: `also prints different for both but I don't care about that currently.` And you should care. It means that PyCharm runs on Python3.x and the server on Python 2.x. These are quite incompatible and most likely the source of your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Holy hells you guys are good. Yeah, i ran python3 Window.py chrom9.fa on the terminal and it worked whereas it didn't work when i ran python Window.py chrom9.fa. You guys are amazing! Thanks  Ian Quah,  Graipher, freakish. (Aaaaaaaaaaaa) (internally screaming)

Still don't know why that happens, but I now know that that's apparently a very serious problem.

Comment: Python protip : If you want to know which Python version was run, you can add thse lines on the top of your program (two lines divided by a `;`) :
`import sys; print(sys.version)`